# R- how to fix memory issues in R?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, import, merge

In all honesty, I'm not quite sure what the issue is but I've had a similar issue in R in the past. I've written code to extract the variables I want from .dat files (specifically the current panel survey). I have CSV files that contain the positions of each variable by year (positions change by year). For example, HRFS12M1 in 2010 is 1173-1174, and in 2019 1223-1224 (and this part of the code is not shown but works so I didn't include it). So I have two folders and two separate directories one with the positions and one with the .dat files. I first loop through the positions files and create dfs with positions for each year (2010-2019). After the position dfs are generated I run the code below to obtain what variables I want in a large merged df. Now the code works as intended when I select 4 or fewer variables in the varList. However, the moment I try to use more variables the df starts to produce values that aren't within those columns. Does anyone know why it's doing this? I've tried several different variables to confirm it's not a problem with the position files but a problem with the number of variables.

```
#Loop through list of .dat files (lst2 contains name of files example:2010dec.dat)
for(i in 1:length(lst2)){
  
  #Import the data cps data set
  temp_cps<-readLines(lst2[i])
  
  #Get the positions of the relevant year
   temp_pos<- get(paste("Year", i, sep = "."))
   
   #List of Variables we are looking at (can't use more than 4)
   **varList=c("HRYEAR4","GESTFIPS","HESP1","HRFS12M1")**
  
   #Get positions only for the variables selected
   temp_pos=temp_pos[grep(paste(varList, collapse="|"), temp_pos$Variable),]
   
  #Create the dataframe
  df<-NULL
    for(j in 1:length(varList)){
    df<-cbind(df,substr(temp_cps,temp_pos$Pos1[j],temp_pos$Pos2[j]))
    }
  df<-as.data.frame(df)
  names(df)<-varList
  assign(paste("CPS", i, sep = "."), df)
  
}

 #AutoMate appending each year
for (k in 1:(length(lst2)-1)){
  
  if(k==1){
    CPS1 <- get(paste("CPS", k, sep = "."))
    CPS2 <- get(paste("CPS", k+1, sep = "."))
    #Append to keep only rows of second data set
    merged_data=rbind(CPS1,CPS2)
  }
  else{
    CPS_C <- get(paste("CPS", k+1, sep = "."))
    merged_data=merged_data=rbind(merged_data,CPS_C)
  }
  if(k==length(lst2)-1){
  
    #Clear Console
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "merged_data"))
    
  }
}
```

[This is what it looks like before it breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9yzQ.png)

[This what happens after adding more than 4 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvg6B.png)

Comment: Is there overlap in your variable names (is one a substring of another)?  I only ask because your grep might not work as expected if you had (say) columns called `ABC` and `ABCD` - searching for `ABC` would return both if I read the code right.  You'd need something like `grep(paste('^', varList, '$', sep = '', collapse="|")` instead, to only match full names

Comment: I know it's hard to represent all the details here, but without a self-contained example that breaks, it's going to be really hard to guess what's going wrong. I think @Hobo could be on the right track potentially. I'd suggest running this all line-by-line outside of the `for` loop and inspecting the results of each object - `temp_cps` / `temp_pos` etc - to make sure it is working as expected at each step.

Comment: None of the variables I tried are subsets but I might add that anyways to error-proof. But for example, if I add HRHHID to the code above it will distort the values and sometimes even swap values in their intended rows. Like year will go to GETFIPS. I don't know if I can add a screenshot to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Need to run a few extra variables to confirm. But the program currently won't work if my list of variables is not in order in terms of position. For example, if "HRYEAR4" is 82-84 and "GESTFIPS" is 93-94 then the program will fail if I put GETSFIPS before HRYEAR4 in varList. However, if HRYEAR comes first then the program will run as intended.  Does anyone, have any quick idea how to replace this line df<-cbind(df,substr(temp_cps,temp_pos$Pos1[j],temp_pos$Pos2[j])) to make it more dynamic and not have this issue? If not, it's not a big deal for the moment I'll just put them in order and see if I can find a better solution in the future. Thanks to anyone who tried to help.